# How do I print only part of a web page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Partial view in a JQuery dialog box that has button links on the side, and text links at the top, and a grid underneath.

I would like to have one of the links at the top be a "Print" link, that prints out the grid an nothing else.

JavaScript's window.print() prints the entire page. How can I print just the grid? Is there someway to tell a print method to "Just print the contents of this div"?

If I need to create a separate "Printable grid" page, how do I avoid printing the "print button" that I assume needs to be on the page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to avoid printing anything is to add a print stylesheet that sets elements that should not print to **display: none**.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

Inside print.css, you can redefine existing CSS styles to **display: none** and you can add a .DoNotPrint class that you can apply to anything that you don't want to print.

```
.DoNotPrint
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: 7 seconds faster.  +1 for the solution.

Comment: So I would have to add the `DoNotPrint` class to anything I want to not print?

Comment: @ABogus - Yes, though as I mentioned, you can set entire elements that you know you don't want to print to display:none in the print.css file.  DoNotPrint would just be for single things that should not print and don't already have a unique CSS class.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends entirely on your implementation but I find the easiest way to achieve this is to include a print specific style sheet like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="URL to your print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

That stylesheet would hide everything but the table and would require nothing special besides addressing which elements to show and hide.

After further consideration, you could also do the following:

Create a separate page that only includes the partial that has the grid.  And when the user clicks the print button,  you open the new window and `window.print()` on load.